# unable to use RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I am trying to use the RABL gem for JSON formatting, but even this simple basic example is not working.

Here is for instance a test method in the controller:

```
def test
    @test={:a=>"toto",:b=>"titi"}
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json  
    end
end
```

and here is the rabl

```
object @test
attributes :a,:b
```

The result is here:

```
[{"titi":{}},{"titi":{}}]
```

In fact, I've made several tries and the same type of result, just like if the filed name were not taken in account....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developper solver my problem: RABL does not work with hash objects, only dotted object ( myObj.myField and not myObj[:myField]). The solution was to convert the hash into an OpenStruct object

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post on this, explaining the issue, and how to get around it:

http://bigtrapeze.com/2012/03/22/using-rabl-to-display-multiple-models/